# Cannot find symbol for makeCopy method in weka java

Tags: java, classification, weka

I am trying to modify cross validation code developed by weka in this [page](https://weka.wikispaces.com/file/view/CrossValidationSingleRun.java/82916749/CrossValidationSingleRun.java). When I paste the exact code the method `.makeCopy(cls)` in the line `Classifier clsCopy = Classifier.makeCopy(cls);` is not exist. Is there any replacement or update for this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classifier has become an interface since Weka 3.7.  Use the  `weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.makeCopy(Classifier)` instead.

Reference : http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Classifier-td32507.html

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Use `AbstractClassifier` which then takes `Classifier` as parameter. `AbstractClassifier` has the method namely `makeCopy`. Do tell me, if that was the case. Here is the [LINK](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/AbstractClassifier.html) to it